# Geeting Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException while retrieving the element from HashMap

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  hashMap.put("1", "adam");
  hashMap.put("2", "john");
  Set<String> keySet = hashMap.keySet();
  System.out.println(keySet);
  Iterator<String> keySetIterator = keySet.iterator();
  while (keySetIterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println("key is " + keySetIterator.next());
    if (keySetIterator.next() == null || keySetIterator.next() == "" || keySetIterator.next().isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("Key Is Empty or null");
    } else {
      //String Key=keySetIterator.next();
      System.out.println("value is  " + hashMap.get(keySetIterator.next()));
    }
  }
}
```

In above code i am using the iterator for iterating the hashmap.

But an exception is raised :

> **Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException**

I am able to fetch the key but i didn't get the value against that key.

Is there any mistake in above code or something which i am using is in wrong way?

Comment: you repedially call `next`. You might want to call it only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake here is that you are calling `keySetIterator.next()` a number of times within one iteration of the loop.

Each time you do, you advance the iterator to the next element.

What you should do instead is store the reference before you do all the tests:

```
while (keySetIterator.hasNext()) {
   String key = keySetIterator.next();
   // test key, retrieve item, etc.
}
```

But note, you don't actually need to check if `key` is not null or empty. The iterator will never return keys that are not in the set in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Each call `keySetIterator.next()` returns next element. So you should use variable to keep next value and use the variable instead calling `next()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  hashMap.put("1", "adam");
  hashMap.put("2", "john");
  Set<String> keySet = hashMap.keySet();
  System.out.println(keySet);
  Iterator<String> keySetIterator = keySet.iterator();
  while (keySetIterator.hasNext()) {
    String nextValue = keySetIterator.next();
    System.out.println("key is " + nextValue);

    if (nextValue == null || nextValue == "" || nextValue.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("Key Is Empty or null");
    } else {
      //String Key=keySetIterator.next();
      System.out.println("value is  " + hashMap.get(nextValue));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @SashaSalauyou may be ) It is another question )

Answer (score 1):

Too many keySetIterator.next(). Truy to put the value in a String at the beginning of your loop:

```
String keyStr = keySetIterator.next();
```

Then use keyStr in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `next()` once before all checks, because subsequent `.next()` moves iterator position one step ahead and returns element on that position:

```
String n = keySetIterator.next();
System.out.println("key is " + Objects.toString(n)); // avoid NPE if n is null
if(n == null || n.isEmpty()) {                       // remove redundant n == ""
    System.out.println("Key Is Empty or null");
} // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Following section. Its not required, If Map is empty it will not enter the loop because `keySetIterator.hasNext()` will return false :

```
System.out.println("key is " +keySetIterator.next());
        if(keySetIterator.next()==null||keySetIterator.next()==""||keySetIterator.next().isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Key Is Empty or null");
        }
```